# WinRT - StreamSocket - Connection closing while reading data via LoadAsync

Tags: javascript, sockets, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to send HTTP requests via StreamSocket, but response is truncated with

**"failedWinRTError: The object has been closed."**

---

Here is my code:

```
  var count, hostName, raw_request, raw_response, reader, socketProtection, startReader, streamSocket, writer;
  streamSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

  hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName("www.reddit.com", "80");

  raw_response = "";

  count = 0;

  startReader = function() {
    return reader.loadAsync(8 * 1000).done(function(bytesRead) {

      raw_response += reader.readString(reader.unconsumedBufferLength);
      if (raw_response.indexOf("</html>") > 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        startReader();
      }
    }, function(error) {

      raw_response += reader.readString(reader.unconsumedBufferLength);
      window.raw_response = raw_response;
      return;
    });
  };

  streamSocket.connectAsync(hostName, "80", 0).done(function(response) {
    var string;

    reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(streamSocket.inputStream);
    reader.inputStreamOptions = 1;

    writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(streamSocket.outputStream);
    string = "Hello world";
    writer.writeString(raw_request);
    return writer.storeAsync().done(function() {
      writer.flushAsync();
      writer.detachStream();
      return startReader();
    });
  });
```

---

I noticed that the beginning of the response is truncated as well.

This is what I get at the beginning of HTTP responses.

> /1.1 200 OK

Also strangely... HTTPS requests work perfectly.

---

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove *http://* from the host name and the second parameter is not needed:

```
var hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName("www.reddit.com");
```

Use this object in *ConnectAsync*, just hostname and service name parameters are needed:

```
streamSocket.connectAsync(hostName, "80").done(function (response) {
    // ....
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**UPDATE:** Ok, if the connection is being closed, probably the server closes it. Are you sending a well formed request? Here is an example:

```
var raw_request, raw_response, reader, writer;
var streamSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

function doRequest() {
    var hostName = new Windows.Networking.HostName("www.reddit.com");
    streamSocket.connectAsync(hostName, "808").then(function () {
        reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(streamSocket.inputStream);
        reader.inputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.partial;
        writer = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(streamSocket.outputStream);

        raw_request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.reddit.com/\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";
        writer.writeString(raw_request);
        return writer.storeAsync();
    }).then(function () {
        raw_response = "";
        return startReader();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

function startReader() {
    return reader.loadAsync(99999999).then(function (bytesRead) {
        raw_response += reader.readString(reader.unconsumedBufferLength);
        if (bytesRead === 0) {
            window.raw_response.value = raw_response;
            return;
        }
        return startReader();
    });
};
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! The http was a typo and I think the request is correct. I think it might be something else going on. I will give it another try! :)